# Live check status does not return database availability

Tags: quarkus

The ready check can implicitly check the database availability by configuration in the `application.properties` by means of the variable: `quarkus.datasource.auth.jdbc.background-validation-interval`. calling the url `q/health/ready` it neatly responds with:

```json
{
    "status": "UP",
    "checks": [
        {
            "name": "Application Health Check",
            "status": "UP",
            "data": {
                "deployed": 1655966187000,
                "groupId": "xxxxxx",
                "artifactId": "xxxxxx",
                "version": "xxxxxx"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Database connections health check",
            "status": "UP"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: our own implementation returns the former check result and Quarkus neatly adds the latter check result.

However the liveness check (`q/health/live`) does not work in the same way. It returns:

```json
{
    "status": "UP",
    "checks": [
        {
            "name": "Application Health Check",
            "status": "UP",
            "data": {
                "deployed": 1655966187000,
                "groupId": "xxxxx",
                "artifactId": "xxxxx",
                "version": "xxxxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We run our code on OpenShift and our pod is hanging and not killed by OpenShift on database `Down` during its operation (liveness checks called).

We could of course configure openshift with `q/health` which gives the former (combined) response as well. However intuitively I would argue that the database availability is also critical for liveness.

Can we somehow configure this out of the box with the proper URL (`q/health/live`)  without writing our own implementation? Are we missing some kind of option in the `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that if the database is down, your application shouldn't be restarted, it should wait for the database node to be restarted and reconnect. Thats why database health is not part of the liveliness check, just part of the readiness. Readiness will covert the part of serving requests, the application will just wait for the database to be back online. Restarting the application node will have no effect on the liveliness of the application.

Comment: Thanks.. we did eventually figure this out as well. The problem that we are facing is a database connection leak. We are still troubleshooting what the problem is here. It seems to have its origination in referring to the new oracle quarkus dependency or to the configuration of a database pool. Or perhaps it was already there but we did not notice it. Anyway.  Time for a minimal reproducer.